# Read & Write files from Input to Output folders: Python

Tags: python

I have written a Python script that reads one file, replaces text, & then outputs it into another file. Instead, I would like to call an input FOLDER that contains multiple files, read these files, & then output them into a destination FOLDER. How would I approach this?

Here is my code:

```
import re

with open("SanitizedFinal_E4300.txt", "rt") as fin:
with open("output6.txt", "wt") as fout:

for line in fin:
    line = line.replace('set system host-name EX4300', 'hostname "EX4300"')
    line = line.replace('set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address', 'ip address')

    line = re.sub(r'set interfaces ge-0/0/0 description (.*)', r'interface 1/1\nname "\1"', line)
    line = re.sub(r'set interfaces ge-0/0/1 description (.*)', r'interface 1/2\nname "\1"', line)
    #and so on...

fout.write(line)
```

I am using Visual Studio Code v1.63.2

Comment: use the `glob` module in Python

Comment: what is wrong with your indentation, this is invalid Python

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.scandir() to iterate over files in a directory:

```
import re, os

for file in os.scandir(input_dir):
    with open(file, "r") as fin, open("path_to_output_dir/" + output_file_name, "w") as fout:
        # whatever file operations you want to do
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read all files in the folder through the OS module, read the contents of each file, and then modify it.

```
import os
fileList = os.listdir(path)
for info in os.listdir(path):
    domain = os.path.abspath(path) #Get folder path
    info = os.path.join(domain,info) #Combining the path with the file name is the full path of each file
    info = open(info,'r') #Read file contents
    #You can modify the file here
    info.close()
```

Comment: the OP uses context managers and you propose to use open-close file, that is back to Python 2.0